# Tool recommendation for converting VB to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

We have a project with over 500,000 lines of VB.NET that we need to convert to C#. Any recommendations, based on experience, for tools to use? We are using Visual Studio 2008 and we're targeting 3.5 .

Comment: Why do you want to convert that large an application between VB and C#?  The two languages are similar enough under the hood that it hardly seems worth the amount of work this is going to take.

Comment: Version 3.5 of what? .NET?

Answer (score 10):

I would concur with the comment. You have 500,000 lines of tried and true VB.NET code. Why on earth would you waste any time changing that? No one says that you can't write all new components in C#.

I would consider not worrying about a tool and instead ask yourself, truly, why you are doing this?

Comment: That's a great question. Right now, my day starts off in VB.Net 1.1 and ends using C# 3.5. After about 18 months of working in two languages and seeing that every new project is written in C#, it's become apparent that our team codes faster in C# - but only because we spend so much time using it.

Comment: I prefer c# myself, but agree that I would much rather leave the VB.net code as is.  What is the value added by doing the conversion?

Comment: I can't speak for Mike, but as for me...  We have an ASP.NET web app that was originally written in VB.NET, but we've been adding to it for some time in C#.  Having to constantly switch between the two definitely slows development, but worse I can't use Visual Studio features like "Go To Definition" or "Find all References" to go from my aspx.vb files to my .cs files in the library.

Comment: Eventually we added a second web app project so we could have aspx files with C# code behind, so now we have two projects in different folders on dev deploying to the same folder on the servers (so they look like one web app).  Because of this I ended up adding build events to copy my css files on dev to the right places to make the same relative paths work that work on live, but as a result I have to rebuild every time I make a style sheet change.

At this point, the one-time pain of just converting everything to C# seems much better.

Answer (score 3):

Reflector will decompile the IL and produce C# for you, it will be rough, but a decent start.

Answer (score 3):

Did this eval a while back.  You will find a lot of "free" solutions that are horrible at edge cases.  This commercial product http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com is by no means perfect; but, was the best we could find at the time doing real conversion tests.  Note: I am speaking only as a customer.  If someone has found a solution that in real-world use produces better conversions than this, please let me know.

Comment: Tangible is the best one I found; be thankful you don't have to go the other way though it's a bit messier!

Answer (score 2):

There used to be an add-in to Reflector which creates a complete Visual Studio solution. However, I don't know if it's still available or working, now that Red Gate has taken over Reflector.

Answer (score 2):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) has a converter built-in IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

The converter from Telerik works well.

http://converter.telerik.com/
http://converter.telerik.com/batch.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've used [this site](http://labs.developerfusion.co.uk/convert/vb-to-csharp.aspx) for a while now for some of my smaller conversions. It has been quite reliable.

According to the site, their converter is based off an [open source IDE](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Features.aspx) that has the converter built in, so you might try the "source site" as well.